# Create a dynamic sequence of pages in swift ios

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I am writing an iOS app using swift. The app is a Tour and takes the user through a series of steps.

Each step has generic properties like so:

```
class Step
{
   var name : String;
   var description : String;
}
```

The step will be displayed in the same way, with Name at the top and a "Next" button at the bottom which moves onto the next step. The standard UI back button will be available at the top as usual.

But, I also want to make certain steps perform certain functions, like:

- show a video
- show a map
- take a picture

I'd like to consolidate each of these step types in to a reusable view or controller.

My question is, what is the best way to structure this in terms of Controllers and Views?

I'm currently using a **StepViewController : UIViewController** with a single View.
When I click NEXT, it creates a new instance of StepViewController, passes it the next step object and adds it to the stack using **instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier**.

Which is the better method...

1. Create a new super-class ViewController of StepViewController for each Step Type, e.g. VideoStepViewController : StepViewController?
2. Create a new View for each Step Type, allowing the master StepViewController to dynamically load a particular View (e.g. VideoView) into the master controller.

Comment: UIPageViewController would be a good option.